# How to intersect values in many-to-many relationship sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have table `Teacher`. It contains many-to-many relationship with table `Student`. Student contains unique column `name`. how can I find all the teachers that contain students with certain names?
For example:
Teacher1 contains Student1 with name "Bob" and Student2 with name "Alice".
Teacher2 contains Student2 with name "Alice" and Student3 with name "Mark".
Teacher3 contains Student1 with name "Bob".
Teacher4 contains Student3 with name "Mark".
I get names `["Alice", "Mark"]`.
In this example I have to get Teacher 1, 2, 4.
How to write this sqlalchemy query?
`session.query(Teacher).filter(...).all()`?

Comment: In SQL you could LEFT JOIN the students table (filtering the students you want) to the teachers table and then COUNT() null values for teacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming that your association many-to-many model/tabele is `StudentTeacher` and you looking for `names=("Alice", "Mark",)`, this query should return what you expected:

```py
results = session.query(
   Teacher
).join(StudentTeacher).join(Student).filter(
   Student.name.in_(names)
).all()
```